# blank page with setState and multiple component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, state

I have an app, in Rust, with a frontend in Typescript.

I have a Switch component, from https://material-ui.com/api/switch/.

```
return(
    <div className={classes.platform}>
    <FormControl>
        <FormGroup>
            <FormControlLabel
                control={
                    <Switch
                        name="HostOnly" 
                        checked={state.HostOnly}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        color="primary"
                    />
                }
                labelPlacement="start"
                label="Host Only"
            />  
            <FormControlLabel
                disabled={state.HostOnly}
                control={
                    <Switch 
                        checked={state.Win64}  
                        name="Win64"
                        color="primary"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                }
                labelPlacement="start"
                label="Windows 64"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
                disabled={state.HostOnly}
                control={
                    <Switch 
                        checked={state.Win32} 
                        name="Win32" 
                        color="primary"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                }
                labelPlacement="start"
                label="Windows 32"
            />
            ....
            );
```

I update their state like this:

```
 const handleChange = (event: any) => {
        setState((state: any) => ({[event.target.name]: event.target.checked}));
        var PlatformStates = {
            name: event.target.name,
            value: event.target.checked
        };
        props.Platform({PlatformStates});
    };
```

The state are declared here:

```
const [state, setState] = useState<any>({
        HostOnly: false,
        Win64: false,
        Win32: false,
    });
```

His parent component get it's state with prop, `<Platforms Platform={Platform} />`

For now, I can change only switch, when I select one other, the previous switch come back to his default position (false).

So I update the handleChnage function as :

```
const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    setState((state: any) => ({...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked}));
    var PlatformStates = {
        name: event.target.name,
        value: event.target.checked
    };
    props.Platform({PlatformStates});
};
```

But now the app renders nothing. I get a blank page. Into console, I have no logs.
I cannot really debug this
So how to get and set the state of multiple switch components?

Thanks

Comment: What page is blank? This component? The parent component? Some other page? Can you try creating a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue? Often times when distilling your code down to a minimal, reproducible example you'll find your issue becomes obvious.